# symfony2 -> doctrine -> flush stops after "START TRANSACTION"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to save some entities into my mysql database and the log stops immediately after this log:

Hint: By saving another entity everything works. That's why I think the connection itself and so on is no problem. Reading the data by getQuery()->getResult() is no problem

```
[2013-09-18 14:25:30] app.INFO: A62 wird persistiert [] []
[2013-09-18 14:25:31] app.INFO: A62 persistiert [] []
[2013-09-18 14:25:31] app.INFO: Before Flush [] []
[2013-09-18 14:25:31] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
```

**This is the corresponding controller-code (a bit shortened):**

```
$immo = new \namespace\MainBundle\Entity\Sale();
$immo->setTitle($bla);
$logger->info($immo->getTitle() . " wird persistiert");
try {
    $em->persist($immo);
    $logger->info($immo->getTitle() . " persistiert");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $logger->err($immo->getTitle()." Error : ".$e->getMessage());
}
...
$logger->info("Before Flush");
$em->flush();
$logger->info("After Flush");
```

**Entities**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="mySaleTableName")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Namespace\MainBundle\Entity\SaleRepository")
 */
class Sale extends BaseImmobilie
{

}

class BaseImmobilie
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $title;

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function setId($x) { $this->id = $x; }

    public function getTitle() { return $this->art; }
    public function setTitle($x) { $this->art = $x; }
}
```

**show full processlist**

```
Id   User    Host    db  Command     Time    State   Info
8528653 dbo441722318    10.46.135.38:55451  NULL    Sleep   0       NULL
8528654 dbo441722318    10.46.135.38:55452  db441722318 Query   0   NULL    show full processlist
```

**Found something (now I can correct my mistake)**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /homepages/8/d90136514/htdocs/symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateType.php on line 44
```

Comment: Is the connection closed? Then check php error log. Does the connection infinetely? Run show processlist on mysql server.

Comment: please read my added hint. other saves and the read of this entity is no problem. this is a normal webserver where I have no root rights

Comment: You can run "show processlist" in phpmyadmin. And I'm sure your webhosting lets you view php errors somewhere. The question if the http connection is closed immediately or hangs is very important, so answer it.

Comment: I redirect the errors via `set_error_handler` but there is no log. I tried the redirected handler with `trigger_error`.

Comment: error handler cannot catch fatal runtime errors, give up this path. If you can't locate the log file, make sure display_errors is on for debugging.

Comment: Do you have any prePersist listeners configured?

Comment: Somewhere, where DateTime object should be set, nonobject is set instead, perhaps string in YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss format